# Combining information from a list

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to link information from a list.

an example follows: I have this list

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> aponta = [ {"date": "10/05/2020", "time": "10:00"}, {"date": "10/05/2020", "time": "15:00"},{"date": "10/05/2020", "time": "20:00"} ];
```

I need you to stay the following way

```
[{"date": "10/05/2020", "time": "10:00 - 15:00 - 20:00"}];
```

does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Could you clarify what your intended result is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not quite apparent what you are asking, so my answers assumes that you need to group by date and then reduce the times.

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> aponta = [ {"date": "10/05/2020", "time": "10:00"}, {"date": "10/05/2020", "time": "15:00"},{"date": "10/05/2020", "time": "20:00"} ];
```

Build a map of lists keyed by the date:

```
Map<String, List<Map<String, dynamic>>> groupedMap = new HashMap();
aponta.forEach((entry) {
    groupedMap..putIfAbsent(entry['date'], () => <Map<String, dynamic>>[]).add(entry);
});
print(groupedMap);
```

[Reduce](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Iterable/reduce.html) each list into one element and collect back to a list:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> finalList = groupedMap.values.map((list) {
    return list.reduce((value, entry) {
       value['time'] += " - " + entry['time'];
       return value;
     });
}).toList();
print(finalList);
```

Result:

```
[{date: 10/05/2020, time: 10:00 - 15:00 - 20:00}]
```